# How to test what started a powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a PowerShell script that can be started either by

- running a shortcut on the desktop, OR
- as a scheduled job from the windows Task Scheduler.

Is there any way within the script itself of identifying *how* it was started? In practice each method produces a slowly scrolling command window on screen, and once it's running I have no way of knowing how it was initiated. The script already logs some data about itself (name, date, time and $PID) but so far I've not found how to test the launch method i.e. task scheduler or manual run.

Comment: I would simply add a switch parameter like `-scheduled`, that I would pass when launching from Task Scheduler.

Comment: you can set a function within the script that tells you who runs it. In regards to who/how runs it, i would use event filtering.

Comment: Do you have PS auditing fully enabled and configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script that is run by Task Scheduler has a parent process whose name is `svchost`, so you can use the following code in your script to detect this:

```
'svchost' -eq (Get-Process -Id (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessID = $pid").ParentProcessId).Name
```